# Linking to Angular App does not show full title

Tags: html, angularjs

When I put a link of my angular app into a social media site or a community forum, the link ist displayed there as standard URL.

Typically the page title should be resolved however.
How do you do that, when the title is dynamically set within angular?

Is there any best practice for setting page titles in routes which can be read from external forums?

Take this as an example: [enter link description here](http://www.raceapp.eu)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your code here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The HTML head originates from an MVC Razor Template and renders as: 
<title ng-bind="'RaceApp'">RaceApp</title>
This should be okay, because the browser shows it correctly in the tab title.